# OpenSSL dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, ssl, struct, openssl

I am working with OpenSSL library. I am trying to access rsa_meth attribute of struct engine_st. The code for doing is as follows:

> ctx->client_cert_engine->rsa_meth

where ctx is of type SSL_CTX *.

I tried to include all the necessary header files but still it is giving me:

`dereferencing pointer to incomplete type.`

Although, if I remove rsa_meth then it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

engine_st (which is what client_cert_engine is) is an internal struct definition (it's in crypto/engine/eng_int.h) and is not exposed in the public header. This is (probably) to prevent a binary compatibility issue in the event of a change to the struct. Instead of trying to dereference, use the getters defined in the engine.h header:

```
 const char *ENGINE_get_id(const ENGINE *e);
 const char *ENGINE_get_name(const ENGINE *e);
 const RSA_METHOD *ENGINE_get_RSA(const ENGINE *e);
 const DSA_METHOD *ENGINE_get_DSA(const ENGINE *e);
 const ECDH_METHOD *ENGINE_get_ECDH(const ENGINE *e);
 const ECDSA_METHOD *ENGINE_get_ECDSA(const ENGINE *e);
 const DH_METHOD *ENGINE_get_DH(const ENGINE *e);
 const RAND_METHOD *ENGINE_get_RAND(const ENGINE *e);
 const STORE_METHOD *ENGINE_get_STORE(const ENGINE *e);
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that RSA_METH structure is not defined. You need to include its definition which is in openssl/rsa.h

Please include openssl/rsa.h or

add

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
```

to your code before this code.

Comment: One more thing, I found out the issue is not with only RSA_METH, I am not able to access any element from client_cert_engine structure. So I am assuming the code is unable to find definition of engine_st structure.

Answer (score 0):

You are dereferencing ctx->client_cert_engine, which is an ENGINE * (pointer to struct engine_st).

Try including `<openssl/engine.h>`.