# Building FreeRDP and make install error: field ‘des3_ctx’ has incomplete type

Tags: c, linux, make-install, freerdp

I was trying to install FreeRDP server using the link : https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki/Compile-on-Ubuntu-16.04

I hit to the below error during `make and make install`

```
[ 25%] Building C object libfreerdp-codec/CMakeFiles/freerdp-codec.dir/nsc.c.o
[ 26%] Building C object libfreerdp-codec/CMakeFiles/freerdp-codec.dir/rfx_sse2.c.o
[ 26%] Linking C shared library libfreerdp-codec.so
[ 26%] Built target freerdp-codec
Scanning dependencies of target freerdp-core
[ 27%] Building C object libfreerdp-core/CMakeFiles/freerdp-core.dir/activation.c.o
In file included from /home/hari/openuds/freerdp/FreeRDP-1.0.2/libfreerdp-core/tls.h:23:0,
                 from /home/hari/openuds/freerdp/FreeRDP-1.0.2/libfreerdp-core/transport.h:33,
                 from /home/hari/openuds/freerdp/FreeRDP-1.0.2/libfreerdp-core/mcs.h:24,
                 from /home/hari/openuds/freerdp/FreeRDP-1.0.2/libfreerdp-core/rdp.h:23,
                 from /home/hari/openuds/freerdp/FreeRDP-1.0.2/libfreerdp-core/activation.h:23,
                 from /home/hari/openuds/freerdp/FreeRDP-1.0.2/libfreerdp-core/activation.c:20:
/home/hari/openuds/freerdp/FreeRDP-1.0.2/libfreerdp-core/crypto.h:67:17: error: field ‘des3_ctx’ has incomplete type
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX des3_ctx;
                 ^~~~~~~~
/home/hari/openuds/freerdp/FreeRDP-1.0.2/libfreerdp-core/crypto.h:72:11: error: field ‘hmac_ctx’ has incomplete type
  HMAC_CTX hmac_ctx;
           ^~~~~~~~
libfreerdp-core/CMakeFiles/freerdp-core.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'libfreerdp-core/CMakeFiles/freerdp-core.dir/activation.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [libfreerdp-core/CMakeFiles/freerdp-core.dir/activation.c.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:494: recipe for target 'libfreerdp-core/CMakeFiles/freerdp-core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [libfreerdp-core/CMakeFiles/freerdp-core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:151: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Why are you asking on stackoverflow instead of asking the freerdp developers??

Comment: It seems like a build issue of code, missing libraries

Comment: Update you version of FreeRDP to one that supports OpenSSL 1.1.0, or downgrade your version of OpenSSL to 1.0.2. Also see [Aggregate ‘BIGNUM foo’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42292027/608639), [OpenSSL dereferencing pointer to incomplete type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16878318/608639), [OpenSSL error incomplete definition of type 'struct ec_key_st'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46546230/608639) and friends.